# How can I iterate over an enum?

Tags: c++, enums

I just noticed that you can not use standard math operators on an `enum` such as `++` or `+=`.

So what is the best way to iterate through all of the values in a C++ `enum`?

Comment: One of many approaches: [When enum Just Isn't Enough: Enumeration Classes for C++](http://www.drdobbs.com/when-enum-just-isnt-enough-enumeration-c/184403955). And, if you want something more encapsulated, try [this approach](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++/msg/d9f99ea5f6787c86) from James Kanze.

Comment: Linked items have some interesting responses.

Comment: These answers don't seem to cover the problem that `int` may not be big enough! (`[C++03: 7.2/5]`)

Comment: Interestingly, you can define `operator++` on enums; however, so you can do `for(Enum_E e = (Enum_E)0; e < ENUM_COUNT; e++)`. Note you have to cast `0` to `Enum_E` because C++ forbids assignment operators on enums.

Comment: If there was a compile time operator, similar to the way sizeof works, that could emit a std::initializer_list literal comprised of the values of the enum, we would have a solution and would not involve any runtime overhead.

Comment: See also (my question): [What are commonly-used ways to iterate over an enum class in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69762598/what-are-commonly-used-ways-to-iterate-over-an-enum-class-in-c)

Answer (score 329, accepted):

The typical way is as follows:

```
enum Foo {
  One,
  Two,
  Three,
  Last
};

for ( int fooInt = One; fooInt != Last; fooInt++ )
{
   Foo foo = static_cast<Foo>(fooInt);
   // ...
}
```

Please note, the enum `Last` is meant to be skipped by the iteration. Utilizing this "fake" `Last` enum, you don't have to update your terminating condition in the for loop to the last "real" enum each time you want to add a new enum.
If you want to add more enums later, just add them before Last. The loop in this example will still work.

Of course, this breaks down if the enum values are specified:

```
enum Foo {
  One = 1,
  Two = 9,
  Three = 4,
  Last
};
```

This illustrates that an enum is not really meant to iterate through. The typical way to deal with an enum is to use it in a switch statement.

```
switch ( foo )
{
    case One:
        // ..
        break;
    case Two:  // intentional fall-through
    case Three:
        // ..
        break;
    case Four:
        // ..
        break;
     default:
        assert( ! "Invalid Foo enum value" );
        break;
}
```

If you really want to enumerate, stuff the enum values in a vector and iterate over that. This will properly deal with the specified enum values as well.

Comment: Note that, in the first part of the example, if you want to use 'i' as a Foo enum and not an int, you will need to static cast it like: static_cast<Foo>(i)

Comment: Also you are skipping Last in the loop. Should be <= Last

Comment: @Tony Last is meant to be skipped.  If you want to add more enums later, add them before Last... the loop in the first example will still work.  By utilizing a "fake" Last enum, you don't have to update your terminating condition in the for loop to the last "real" enum each time you want to add a new enum.

Comment: Except now you've actually allocated memory when an enum, provided it is zero-indexed and strictly continous, can do that task without allocating memory.

Comment: It would be awesome to paste @Tony's comment into the answer. I was really confused by that.

Comment: You can also use macros but that means you need to define your enum via macro as well. This way you actually avoid casting and don't have to use vector at all!

Comment: @tsusanka It operates on the same logic as iterating over an STL containter, actually.  Just as `std::end()` returns an "after-the-end" iterator so you can use `i < std::end(whatever)` or `it != std::end(whatever)`, it can be useful to add a dummy value at the end of an `enum` so you can use `i < Last`.  Similarly, if an enum is meant to be used for iteration, it can also be useful to add a dummy `First` element, whose underlying value is the same as the actual first element's value.  In this answer, for example, it could be something like `First = One`.

Comment: Note that for this enum definition to be safe for updates one should define a value `UNKNOWN = 0`. Additionally, I would suggest to just drop the `default` case when switching over enum values since it might hide cases where handling of values was forgotten until runtime. Instead one should hardcode all values and use the `UNKNOWN` field to detect incompatibilities.

Comment: @timidpueo That's why I prefer to call the last entry `Count`. Makes it a little more obvious.

Comment: @Cerno Right.  Also, it's wise to add a comment such as "Do not assign values because this is iterated over.  See xxx::count."

Comment: @cloud: The compiler will optimize out the "extra" variable.  Removing temporary variables that clarify the code is not a good way to optimize, because it (a) usually doesn't  actually optimize, and (b) it reduces clarity.

Answer (score 89):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

namespace MyEnum
{
  enum Type
  {
    a = 100,
    b = 220,
    c = -1
  };

  static const Type All[] = { a, b, c };
}

void fun( const MyEnum::Type e )
{
  std::cout << e << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  // all
  for ( const auto e : MyEnum::All )
    fun( e );

  // some
  for ( const auto e : { MyEnum::a, MyEnum::b } )
    fun( e );

  // all
  std::for_each( std::begin( MyEnum::All ), std::end( MyEnum::All ), fun );

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Note that if you're crossing files/classes and if MS compatibility is giving you issues with header-declared non-integer constants, it helps under my compiler to explicitly put the size in the type in the header: `static const Type All[3];` and then I'm able to initialize in the source: `const MyEnum::Type MyEnum::All[3] = { a, b, c };`  Before doing that, I was getting obnoxious `Error in range-based for...` errors (because the array had an unknown size).  Figured this out thanks to [a related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7939414/527489)

Comment: The array version is very friendly of copy paste. The most satisfactory answer besides, "NO" or "only for sequential". Probably macro friendly even.

Comment: this might be a good solution for enums with small number of items, but for enums with big number of items it must not fit well.

Answer (score 46):

With [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11), there actually is an alternative: writing a templatized custom iterator.

Let's assume your enum is

```
enum class foo {
  one,
  two,
  three
};
```

This generic code will do the trick, quite efficiently. Place it in a generic header, and it'll serve you for any enum you may need to iterate over:

```
#include <type_traits>
template < typename C, C beginVal, C endVal>
class Iterator {
  typedef typename std::underlying_type<C>::type val_t;
  int val;
public:
  Iterator(const C & f) : val(static_cast<val_t>(f)) {}
  Iterator() : val(static_cast<val_t>(beginVal)) {}
  Iterator operator++() {
    ++val;
    return *this;
  }
  C operator*() { return static_cast<C>(val); }
  Iterator begin() { return *this; } //default ctor is good
  Iterator end() {
      static const Iterator endIter=++Iterator(endVal); // cache it
      return endIter;
  }
  bool operator!=(const Iterator& i) { return val != i.val; }
};
```

You'll need to specialize it

```
typedef Iterator<foo, foo::one, foo::three> fooIterator;
```

And then you can iterate using range-for

```
for (foo i : fooIterator() ) { // Notice the parentheses!
   do_stuff(i);
}
```

The assumption that you don't have gaps in your enum is still true; there is no assumption on the number of bits actually needed to store the enum value (thanks to `std::underlying_type`).

Comment: please note that the "generic code" is tied to "foo" (see the code about the middle), so you can't actually use it with other enum definitions.

Comment: @lepe ? You just make a different typedef for a different enum.

Comment: @lepe That's like saying that `std::vector` isn't generic because `std::vector<foo>` is tied to `foo`.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus, @Kyle: So if I have another enum like: `enum color { green = 20, white = 30, red = 40 }` How can I use the above code without changing the `foo operator*() { ...` part? Can someone explain with an example code? (Sorry my C++ skills are not that advanced yet).

Comment: @lepe Because of the skip, you would have to specialize operator ++ to use val+=10 in lieu of ++val.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus: sorry, my bad... I set those values to make it different to foo, but its not what I'm concern about. Please change from my previous comment and set enum to be: `enum color { green, black, white, blue, red }` . How do I need to use the code proposed by Francesco so I can iterate either `foo` or `color` without having to modify his code? If possible, I would like to see an example code.

Comment: `typedef Iterator<color, color::green, color::red> colorIterator;` Make sure you understand how the template instantiations work.

Comment: @lepe Each enum will have its *own* (template-specialized) iterator type, just like you'd need a different `std::vector` type to hold different types of objects. This is accomplished via template specialization, as in the previous comment. The point is that you don't need to redefine the `Iterator` template for each unique enum type, just like you don't need to redefine the `std::vector` template for each object type; you just specialize it, which can be done with a one-line `typedef`.

Comment: @lepe To solve the "skips" problem in a somewhat-generic (though limited) way, see my answer below. Also, note that you can only tag one person in a comment (so I didn't get notified when you tried to tag me).

Comment: Oh, I see the issue -- `foo operator*() {  ...` should be `C operator*() {  ...`.

Comment: @KyleStrand:  You got it! that makes totally sense now. Should the code be updated? Thanks everyone for your explanations.

Comment: I've actually created a somewhat more generic version here: https://github.com/BatmanAoD/PublicPaste/blob/master/GenericCppCode/EnumIterator.cpp

Comment: And by "more generic" I mean that it relies on an overloaded global function called `IsEnumValid` (which could easily be moved into a namespace) to determine whether or not particular int-values are valid enum values, which solves the "skipping" problem. One alternative would be to make the validity-checking function one of the template parameters. Another would be to require the existence of a static array for iteration, as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/26910769/1858225

Comment: When this is a sequential ordinal numeric enum, this would work. What about when you have a disjoint set of bit flags? Including combinations thereof.

Comment: definitely +1, but a) why the `val` member data is of the `int` type but not the `val_t` ? and b) would it be useful to override also the `==` operator along with the `!=` one ?

Answer (score 30):

These solutions are too complicated. I do like this:

```
enum NodePosition { Primary = 0, Secondary = 1, Tertiary = 2, Quaternary = 3};

const NodePosition NodePositionVector[] = { Primary, Secondary, Tertiary, Quaternary };

for (NodePosition pos : NodePositionVector) {
...
}
```

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted.  It's a reasonable solution.

Comment: I expect it was because the entries need to be maintained in two places.

Comment: Does C++ permit the `for (NodePosition pos : NodePositionVector)` syntax? As far as I'm aware this is Java syntax, and you'll need iterators in C++ to do something equivalent.

Comment: @thegreatjedi Since C++11 you can, even simpier : for(auto pos : NodePositionVector) {..}

Comment: @thegreatjedi It would have been quicker to search, or even compile a test program, than to ask that question. But yes, since C++11 it is perfectly valid C++ syntax, which the compiler translates to the equivalent (and far more verbose/less abstracting) code, usually via iterators; see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). And, as Enzojz said, C++11 also added `auto`, so you don't have to declare the type of the elements explicitly, unless you (A) need to use a conversion operator or (B) don't like `auto` for some reason. Most range-`for` users use `auto` AFAICT

Comment: Here's an extension of that approach:

    `enum class Foo { a, b };
    
    template <typename T>
    struct enum_values;
    
    template <>
    struct enum_values<Foo> {    
        static constexpr std::array<Foo,2> values() {
            return { Foo::a, Foo::b };  
        }
    };`

Then you can do `for (Foo f : enum_values<Foo>::values())`, so you don't need to have variable names named after types (`NodePositionVector`). You still need to maintain it, of course. It would be nice if the language provided this functionality.

Comment: @Enzojz: Just want to emphasize that this code does not work with any C++ older then 11: `range-based 'for' loops only available with '-std=c++11'`

Comment: The down side is that you have to maintain `NodePosition` and `NodePositionVector` in sync.

Comment: Approach is ok, imlementation is flawed. I do not recommend naming arrays as Vectors (it is outright confusing), and re-using NodePositionVector , while potentially technically valid, is outright confusing, which insults Almighty Readability.  -1.

Comment: How about using MACRO to keep those entries in one place?

Answer (score 22):

I often do it like this:

```
    enum EMyEnum
    {
        E_First,
        E_Orange = E_First,
        E_Green,
        E_White,
        E_Blue,
        E_Last
    }

    for (EMyEnum i = E_First; i < E_Last; i = EMyEnum(i + 1))
    {}
```

Or if not successive, but with regular steps (e.g., bit flags):

```
    enum EAnimalCaps
    {
        E_None    = 0,
        E_First   = 0x1,
        E_CanFly  = E_First,
        E_CanWalk = 0x2
        E_CanSwim = 0x4,
        E_Last
    }

    class MyAnimal
    {
       EAnimalCaps m_Caps;
    }

    class Frog
    {
        Frog() :
            m_Caps(EAnimalCaps(E_CanWalk | E_CanSwim))
        {}
    }

    for (EAnimalCaps= E_First; i < E_Last; i = EAnimalCaps(i << 1))
    {}
```

Comment: but, what's the use of printing the values bit-wise?

Comment: To use enums to create bitmasks. e.g. combine several options in single variable, then using the FOR to test for every option. Fixed my post with better example.

Comment: I still can't get the use of it(& your post still shows the old example)! Using enum as bitmasks are really helpful, but didn't able to connect the dots! could you please elaborate a bit in your example in details, you can put the additional code as well.

Comment: @anu Sorry did not see your comment. Added Frog class as bitmask example

Comment: Wouldn't you need to start at your 0x1 element? Otherwise you're bitshifting a whole lot 0s, and thereby remain at the first element indefinitely

Comment: You are correct @Tare , fixed the example.

Comment: That is a code dump, and an explanation would be in order. E.g, what is the idea? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41718764/edit), not here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 16):

If your enum starts with 0 and the increment is always 1.

```
enum enumType
{
    A = 0,
    B,
    C,
    enumTypeEnd
};

for(int i=0; i<enumTypeEnd; i++)
{
   enumType eCurrent = (enumType) i;
}
```

If not, I guess the only way is to create something like a

```
vector<enumType> vEnums;
```

add the items, and use normal iterators...

Comment: The "<" operator is not available for enums.

Comment: `i<enumTypeEnd` does also do an implicit cast

Answer (score 14):

Assuming that enum is numbered sequentially is error prone. Moreover, you may want to iterate over selected enumerators only. If that subset is small, looping over it explicitly might be an elegant choice:

```
enum Item { Man, Wolf, Goat, Cabbage }; // or enum class

for (auto item : {Wolf, Goat, Cabbage}) { // or Item::Wolf, ...
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This is a nice option I think. Must be part of a newer C++ spec than I was using when I asked the question I'm guessing?

Comment: Yes. It iterates over an std::initializer_list<Item>. [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list).

Answer (score 9):

Something that hasn't been covered in the other answers = if you're using strongly typed C++11 enums, you cannot use `++` or `+ int` on them.  In that case, a bit of a messier solution is required:

```
enum class myenumtype {
  MYENUM_FIRST,
  MYENUM_OTHER,
  MYENUM_LAST
}

for(myenumtype myenum = myenumtype::MYENUM_FIRST;
    myenum != myenumtype::MYENUM_LAST;
    myenum = static_cast<myenumtype>(static_cast<int>(myenum) + 1)) {

  do_whatever(myenum)

}
```

Comment: ...but C++11 introduces the range based for that is shown in other answers. :-)

Answer (score 9):

Casting the variable to an `int&` lets you increment while keeping the type readable.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

enum MyEnum
{
    ONE,
    TWO,
    THREE,
    FOUR,
};

int main()
{
    for (MyEnum v = MyEnum::ONE; v <= MyEnum::FOUR; ++(int&)v)
    {
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
0
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 8):

```cpp
enum class A {
    a0=0, a3=3, a4=4
};
constexpr std::array<A, 3> ALL_A {A::a0, A::a3, A::a4}; // constexpr is important here

for(A a: ALL_A) {
  if(a==A::a0 || a==A::a4) std::cout << static_cast<int>(a);
}
```

A `constexpr std::array` can iterate even non-sequential enums without the array being instantiated by the compiler. This depends on things like the compiler's optimization heuristics and whether you take the array's address.

In my experiments, I found that `g++` 9.1 with `-O3` will optimize away the above array if there are 2 non-sequential values or quite a few sequential values (I tested up to 6). But it only does this if you have an `if` statement. (I tried a statement that compared an integer value greater than all the elements in a sequential array and it inlined the iteration despite none being excluded, but when I left out the if statement, the values were put in memory.) It also inlined 5 values from a non-sequential enum in [one case|https://godbolt.org/z/XuGtoc]. I suspect this odd behavior is due to deep heuristics having to do with caches and branch prediction.

Here is a [link to a simple test iteration on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/vaD3py) that demonstrates the array does not always get instantiated.

The price of this technique is writing the enum elements twice and keeping the two lists in sync.

Comment: I like simple range-like for-loop semantics and I think it will evolve even more which is why I like this solution.

Answer (score 6):

You can't with an enum.  Maybe an enum isn't the best fit for your situation.

A common convention is to name the last enum value something like MAX and use that to control a loop using an int.

Comment: There are several examples here that demonstrate the opposite. I your own statement you are contradicting yourself (second line).

Comment: @Niki He is right when telling "can't with enum". All the answers demonstrate "tricks" to iterate over another thing, as if iterating over enum.

Answer (score 4):

You can try and define the following macro:

```
#define for_range(_type, _param, _A1, _B1) for (bool _ok = true; _ok;)\
for (_type _start = _A1, _finish = _B1; _ok;)\
    for (int _step = 2*(((int)_finish)>(int)_start)-1;_ok;)\
         for (_type _param = _start; _ok ; \
 (_param != _finish ? \
           _param = static_cast<_type>(((int)_param)+_step) : _ok = false))
```

Now you can use it:

```
enum Count { zero, one, two, three };

    for_range (Count, c, zero, three)
    {
        cout << "forward: " << c << endl;
    }
```

It can be used to iterate backwards and forwards through unsigned, integers, enums and chars:

```
for_range (unsigned, i, 10,0)
{
    cout << "backwards i: " << i << endl;
}


for_range (char, c, 'z','a')
{
    cout << c << endl;
}
```

Despite its awkward definition, it is optimized very well. I looked at the [disassembly](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disassembly#Noun) in [VC++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B).
The code is extremely efficient. Don't be put off by the three *for* statements: the compiler will produce only one loop after optimization! You can even define enclosed loops:

```
unsigned p[4][5];

for_range (Count, i, zero,three)
    for_range(unsigned int, j, 4, 0)
    {
        p[i][j] = static_cast<unsigned>(i)+j;
    }
```

You obviously cannot iterate through enumerated types with gaps.

Comment: That's a wonderful hack! Although it is more appropriate for C than for C++, one might say.

Comment: `_A1` is not an allowed name, it is a leading underscore with a following capital letter.

Answer (score 3):

You can also overload the increment/decrement operators for your enumerated type.

Comment: You can't overload any operators on C or C++ enumerated types. Unless you were to create a struct/class that emulated an enumeration of values.

Comment: C++ allows overloading operators on enums.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571456/operators-overloading-for-enums .

Comment: Overloading the increment/decrement requires making a decision on what to do when there is an overflow

Answer (score 3):

Here's another solution which only works for contiguous enums.  It gives the expected iteration, except for ugliness in the increment, which is where it belongs, since that's what's broken in C++.

```
enum Bar {
    One = 1,
    Two,
    Three,
    End_Bar // Marker for end of enum; 
};

for (Bar foo = One; foo < End_Bar; foo = Bar(foo + 1))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Incrementing can be shortened to `foo = Bar(foo + 1)`.

Comment: Thanks, HolyBlackCat, I've incorporated your excellent suggestion!

I also notice that Riot has pretty much this same solution, but conformant with strong typing (and thus more verbose).

Answer (score 3):

Here are some very readable and easy-to-understand approaches, for both *weakly-typed* C and C++ regular `enum`s, *and* *strongly-typed* C++ `enum class`es.

I recommend compiling all examples below with [`-Wall`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wall), [`-Wextra`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wextra), and [`-Werror`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Werror) by adding `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` to your build command. This gives you the added safety that if you forget to cover any enum value in the `switch` case your compiler will *throw a compile-time [`switch`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wswitch) error*! This forces you to keep your enum definition and switch cases in-sync, which is an extra safety measure for your code. This tip works so long as you:

1. Cover *all* enum values in your `switch` case, and
2. Do *not* have a `default` switch case.
3. Build with the `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` flags.

I recommend you follow all three of those points, as it is a good practice and creates better code.

### 1. For a standard, *weakly-typed* C or C++ `enum`:

**C definition (this is also valid C++):**

```c
typedef enum my_error_type_e
{
    MY_ERROR_TYPE_SOMETHING_1 = 0,
    MY_ERROR_TYPE_SOMETHING_2,
    MY_ERROR_TYPE_SOMETHING_3,
    MY_ERROR_TYPE_SOMETHING_4,
    MY_ERROR_TYPE_SOMETHING_5,
    /// Not a valid value; this is the number of members in this enum
    MY_ERROR_TYPE_count,
    // helpers for iterating over the enum
    MY_ERROR_TYPE_begin = 0,
    MY_ERROR_TYPE_end = MY_ERROR_TYPE_count,
} my_error_type_t;
```

**C++ definition:**

```cpp
enum my_error_type_t
{
    MY_ERROR_TYPE_SOMETHING_1 = 0,
    MY_ERROR_TYPE_SOMETHING_2,
    MY_ERROR_TYPE_SOMETHING_3,
    MY_ERROR_TYPE_SOMETHING_4,
    MY_ERROR_TYPE_SOMETHING_5,
    /// Not a valid value; this is the number of members in this enum
    MY_ERROR_TYPE_count,
    // helpers for iterating over the enum
    MY_ERROR_TYPE_begin = 0,
    MY_ERROR_TYPE_end = MY_ERROR_TYPE_count,
};
```

**C or C++ iteration over this *weakly-typed* enum:**

Note: incrementing an enum by doing `my_error_type++` is *not* allowed--not even on C-style enums, so we must do this instead: `my_error_type = (my_error_type_t)(my_error_type + 1)`. Notice that `my_error_type + 1` *is* allowed, however, since this weak enum is automatically implicitly cast to an `int` here to make this addition possible with*out* having to manually cast it to an int like this: `my_error_type = (my_error_type_t)((int)my_error_type + 1)`.

```cpp
for (my_error_type_t my_error_type = MY_ERROR_TYPE_begin;
        my_error_type < MY_ERROR_TYPE_end;
        my_error_type = (my_error_type_t)(my_error_type + 1))
{
    switch (my_error_type)
    {
        case MY_ERROR_TYPE_SOMETHING_1:
            break;
        case MY_ERROR_TYPE_SOMETHING_2:
            break;
        case MY_ERROR_TYPE_SOMETHING_3:
            break;
        case MY_ERROR_TYPE_SOMETHING_4:
            break;
        case MY_ERROR_TYPE_SOMETHING_5:
            break;
        case MY_ERROR_TYPE_count:
            // This case will never be reached.
            break;
    }
}
```

### 2. For a *scoped*, *strongly-typed* C++ `enum class`:

**C++ definition:**

```cpp
enum class my_error_type_t
{
    SOMETHING_1 = 0,
    SOMETHING_2,
    SOMETHING_3,
    SOMETHING_4,
    SOMETHING_5,
    /// Not a valid value; this is the number of members in this enum
    count,
    // helpers for iterating over the enum
    begin = 0,
    end = count,
};
```

**C++ iteration over this *strongly-typed* enum:**

Notice the extra `(size_t)` cast (or `(int)` would be acceptable too) required to forcefully increment the `enum class` variable! I also chose to use the C++-style `static_cast<my_error_type_t>` cast here, but a C-style `(my_error_type_t)` cast, as done above, would have been fine as well.

```cpp
for (my_error_type_t my_error_type = my_error_type_t::begin;
        my_error_type < my_error_type_t::end;
        my_error_type = static_cast<my_error_type_t>((size_t)my_error_type + 1))
{
    switch (my_error_type)
    {
        case my_error_type_t::SOMETHING_1:
            break;
        case my_error_type_t::SOMETHING_2:
            break;
        case my_error_type_t::SOMETHING_3:
            break;
        case my_error_type_t::SOMETHING_4:
            break;
        case my_error_type_t::SOMETHING_5:
            break;
        case my_error_type_t::count:
            // This case will never be reached.
            break;
    }
}
```

Also notice the scoping. In the C++ *strongly-typed* `enum class` I used `my_error_type_t::` to access each scoped `enum class` member. But, in the C-style *weakly-typed* regular `enum`, very similar scoping can be achieved, as I demonstrated, simply be prefixing each `enum` member name with `MY_ERROR_TYPE_`. So, the fact that the C++ *strongly-typed* `enum class` adds scoping doesn't really add much value—it's really just a personal preference in that regard.

And the fact that the C++ *strongly-typed* `enum class` has extra type-safety also has pros and cons. It may help you in some cases but it definitely makes incrementing the enum and iterating over it a pain-in-the-butt, which, honestly, means it is doing its job.

By making it *harder* to increment the scoped `enum class` variable as though it was an integer, the C++ *strongly-typed* `enum class` is doing *exactly what it was designed to do*. Whether or not you *want* that behavior is up to you. Personally, I frequently do *not* want that behavior, and so it is not uncommon for me to prefer to use C-style enums even in C++.

### See also:

1. [my answer] [Is there a way to initialize a vector by index in c++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70889843/4561887)
2. [my Q&A] [What are commonly-used ways to iterate over an enum class in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69762598/what-are-commonly-used-ways-to-iterate-over-an-enum-class-in-c/69762682#69762682)
3. My answer on some of the differences between `enum class`es (*strongly-typed* enums) and regular `enum`s (*weakly-typed* enums) in C++: [How to automatically convert strongly typed enum into int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357240/how-to-automatically-convert-strongly-typed-enum-into-int/65014885#65014885)
4. [Some of my personal notes on the `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` and other build options](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world#additional-c-and-c-build-notes-ex-wgcc-or-clang-compilers), from my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repository.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not like to pollute you enum with a final COUNT item (because maybe if you also use the enum in a switch then then the compiler will warn you of a missing case COUNT:), you can do this:

```
enum Colour {Red, Green, Blue};
const Colour LastColour = Blue;

Colour co(0);
while (true) {
  // do stuff with co
  // ...
  if (co == LastColour) break;
  co = Colour(co+1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Upsides: enums can have any values you like in any order you like and it's still easy to iterate over them.
Names and values are defined once, in the first #define.

Downsides: if you use this at work, you need a whole paragraph to explain it to your coworkers. And, it's annoying to have to declare memory to give your loop something to iterate over, but I don't know of a workaround that doesn't confine you to enums with adjacent values (and if the enum will always have adjacent values, the enum might not be buying you all that much anyway.)

```
//create a, b, c, d as 0, 5, 6, 7
#define LIST x(a) x(b,=5) x(c) x(d)
#define x(n, ...) n __VA_ARGS__,
enum MyEnum {LIST}; //define the enum
#undef x //needed
#define x(n,...) n ,
MyEnum myWalkableEnum[] {LIST}; //define an iterable list of enum values
#undef x //neatness

int main()
{
  std::cout << d;
  for (auto z : myWalkableEnum)
    std::cout << z;
}
//outputs 70567
```

The trick of declaring a list with an undefined macro wrapper, and then defining the wrapper differently in various situations, has a lot of applications other than this one.

Comment: I don't believe this should be downvoted. It's a portable solution that works with enums that are not consecutive; and other answers involving arrays were upvoted. Mine has the advantage that you don';t have to define the enum values twice and keep two definitions in sync, and it showcases a useful trick for interpreting tokens multiple ways with undef and define that is generally applicable to many problems. 
Unless and until we get enum ++, -- and iterators, there's simply no clean way to do it. This is the cleanest of the workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

There is already a discussion about `std::initializer_list` ([C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11)) in the comments.
I am mentioning an example to iterate over the enum.

Or `std::initializer_list` and a simpler syntax:

```
enum E {
    E1 = 4,
    E2 = 8,
    // ..
    En
};

constexpr std::initializer_list<E> all_E = {E1, E2, /*..*/ En};
```

**and then**

```
for (auto e : all_E) {
    // Do job with e
}
```

[Reference](https://riptutorial.com/cplusplus/example/13085/iteration-over-an-enum#:%7E:text=C%2B%2B%20Iteration%20over%20an%20enum&text=There%20is%20no%20built%2Din%20to%20iterate%20over%20enumeration.)

Comment: What comments? Where?

Answer (score 2):

(Taking [Marski's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261963/how-can-i-iterate-over-an-enum/57023705#57023705) as a big hint...)

Since the body of an enum definition is the same as an initialiser list, it is possible to do this without repeating the item list if we use a simple macro to write out the values:

```
#define ITEM_LIST_MACRO Wolf, Goat, Cabbage

enum Item { ITEM_LIST_MACRO }; // Define the enum

// Now iterate through it
for (auto item : { ITEM_LIST_MACRO }) {
}
```

Pros: It is simple, without any repetition, and there isn't any need to maintain annoying first/last sentinel values.  (Indeed I think this might be the only solution suggested so far that does not require the user to remember to update an 'end' marker when a new item is added to the list.)

Cons: It doesn't work with scoped enums (enum class), because the initialiser list would need the scope (Item::Wolf, etc.). Also, it doesn't work if you want to specify the values of the enum members rather than having them defaulted.

Answer (score 1):

For [Microsoft compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B):

```
#define inc_enum(i) ((decltype(i)) ((int)i + 1))

enum enumtype { one, two, three, count};
for(enumtype i = one; i < count; i = inc_enum(i))
{
    dostuff(i);
}
```

Note: this is a lot less code than the simple templatized custom iterator answer.

You can get this to work with [GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) by using `typeof` instead of `decltype`, but I don't have that compiler handy at the moment to make sure it compiles.

Comment: This was written ~5 years after `decltype` became standard C++, so you should not recommend the outdated `typeof` from ancient GCC. Vaguely recent GCC handles `decltype` just fine. There are other issues: C-style casts are discouraged, & macros worse. Proper C++ features can give the same generic functionality. This would be better rewritten to use `static_cast` & a template function: `template <typename T> auto inc_enum(T const t) { return static_cast<T>(static cast<int>(t) + 1); }`. And casts aren't needed for non-`enum class`. Alternatively, operators can be overloaded per `enum` type (TIL)

Answer (score 1):

In [Bjarne Stroustrup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bjarne_Stroustrup)'s C++ programming language book, you can read that he's proposing to overload the `operator++` for your specific `enum`. `enum` are user-defined types and overloading operator exists in the language for these specific situations.

You'll be able to code the following:

```
#include <iostream>
enum class Colors{red, green, blue};
Colors& operator++(Colors &c, int)
{
     switch(c)
     {
           case Colors::red:
               return c=Colors::green;
           case Colors::green:
               return c=Colors::blue;
           case Colors::blue:
               return c=Colors::red; // Managing overflow
           default:
               throw std::exception(); // Or do anything else to manage the error...
     }
}

int main()
{
    Colors c = Colors::red;
    // Casting in int just for convenience of output. 
    std::cout << (int)c++ << std::endl;
    std::cout << (int)c++ << std::endl;
    std::cout << (int)c++ << std::endl;
    std::cout << (int)c++ << std::endl;
    std::cout << (int)c++ << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Test code: http://cpp.sh/357gb

Mind that I'm using `enum class`. The code also works fine with `enum`. But I prefer `enum class` since they are strongly typed and can prevent us from make a mistake at compile time.

Comment: A downvote was cast on this post. Any reason why would it will not answer to the question ?

Comment: The reason is probably because this is a terrible solution architecturally speaking: it forces you to write global-meant-to logic binded to a specific component (your enumeration), moreover if your enumeration does change for whatever reason you are forced to edit your ++ operator too, as an approach it is not sustainable for any medium-large scale project, it is not a surprise it comes from a Bjarne Stroustrup's recommendation, back in the days software architecture was like science fiction

Comment: Original question is about having operator to an `enum`. It wasn't a architectural question. I don't believe that in 2013 C++ was a science fiction.

Comment: I don't think people here are looking for bad solutions, which this one definitely is, and therefore downvoted. I just added my downvote too btw

Comment: I upvote as it is an interesting concept, functional, and the other statements are personal bias.

Answer (score 1):

Extending [Eponymous's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261963/how-can-i-iterate-over-an-enum/56332539#56332539): It's great, but it doesn't provide a general syntax. Here's what I came up with:

#### File *Common/EnumTools.h*

```
#pragma once

#include <array>

namespace Common {

// Here we forward-declare metafunction for mapping enums to their values.
// Since C++<23 doesn't have reflection, you have to populate it yourself :-(
// Usage: After declaring enum class E, add this overload in the namespace of E:
// inline constexpr auto allValuesArray(const E&, Commob::EnumAllValuesTag) { return std::array{E::foo, E::bar}; }
// Then `AllValues<NS::E>` will call `allValuesArray(NS::E{}, EnumAllValuesTag)` which will resolve
// by ADL.
// Just be sure to keep it sync'd with your enum!

// Here's what you want to use in, e.g., loops: "for (auto val : Common::AllValues<MyEnum>) {"

struct EnumAllValuesTag {}; // So your allValuesArray function is clearly associated with this header.

template <typename Enum>
static inline constexpr auto AllValues = allValuesArray(Enum{}, EnumAllValuesTag{});
// ^ Just "constexpr auto" or "constexpr std::array<Enum, allValuesArray(Enum{}, EnumAllValuesTag{}).size()>" didn't work on all compilers I'm using, but this did.

} // namespace Common
```

Then in your namespace:

```
#include "Common/EnumTools.h"

namespace MyNamespace {

enum class MyEnum {
    foo,
    bar = 4,
    baz = 42,
};

// Making this not have to be in the `Common` namespace took some thinking,
// but is a critical feature since otherwise there's no hope in keeping it sync'd with the enum.
inline constexpr auto allValuesArray(const MyEnum&, Common::EnumAllValuesTag) {
    return std::array{ MyEnum::foo, MyEnum::bar, MyEnum::baz };
}

} // namespace MyNamespace
```

Then wherever you need to use it:

```
for (const auto& e : Common::AllValues<MyNamespace::MyEnum>) { ... }
```

So even if you've typedef'd:

```
namespace YourNS {
using E = MyNamespace::MyEnum;
} // namespace YourNS

for (const auto& e : Common::AllValues<YourNS::E>) { ... }
```

I can't think of anything much better, short of the actual language feature everyone looking at this page want.

Future work:

1. You should be able to add a `constexpr` function (and so a metafunction) that filters `Common::AllValues<E>` to provide a `Common::AllDistinctValues<E>` for the case of enums with repeated numerical values like `enum { foo = 0, bar = 0 };`.
2. I bet there's a way to use the compiler's `switch`-covers-all-`enum`-values to write `allValuesArray` such that it errors if the enum has added a value.

Comment: That's interesting. I ended up using only `inline constexpr auto allValuesArray() {
    return std::array{ MyEnum::foo, MyEnum::bar, MyEnum::baz };
}` since I need to spell it out one by one anyway. That's for me the simplest solution. (btw: with your code I saw clang-7 crashing. fun fun fun XD)

Answer (score 0):

If you knew that the enum values were sequential, for example the Qt:Key enum, you could:

```
Qt::Key shortcut_key = Qt::Key_0;
for (int idx = 0; etc...) {
    ....
    if (shortcut_key <= Qt::Key_9) {
        fileMenu->addAction("abc", this, SLOT(onNewTab()),
                            QKeySequence(Qt::CTRL + shortcut_key));
        shortcut_key = (Qt::Key) (shortcut_key + 1);
    }
}
```

It works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef enum{
    first = 2,
    second = 6,
    third = 17
}MyEnum;

static const int enumItems[] = {
    first,
    second,
    third
}

static const int EnumLength = sizeof(enumItems) / sizeof(int);

for(int i = 0; i < EnumLength; i++){
    //Do something with enumItems[i]
}
```

Comment: This solution will create a unnecessarily static variables in memory while the objective of enum is just to create a 'mask' to constants inlined

Comment: Unless changed to `constexpr static const int enumItems[]`

Answer (score 0):

Using a lambda, I found this is the best (modern) way of looping over enums.
This highly improves the abstraction.

One can even make it a template, so it's applicable to any enum.
This code neither gives you issues with [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) (and [Clang-Tidy](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/)).

```cpp
#include <functional>

/// @brief Loop over all enum values where the last enum value is the invalid one
void forEachAction(std::function<void(Enum)> &&doThis) {
    for (int value = 0; value = static_cast<int>(Enum::LastValue); ++value ) {
        doThis(static_cast<Enum>(value ));
    }
}

...

forEachAction([this](Enum value) {
    ...  // What you want to execute for every enum
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Most solutions are based on loops over the (MIN, MAX) range, but they overlook the fact that might be holes in the enum.

My suggestions is:

```
        for (int i = MYTYPE_MIN; i <= MYTYPE_MAX; i++) {
            if (MYTYPE_IsValid(i)) {
                MYTYPE value = (MYTYPE)i;
                // DoStuff(value)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Awesome! So now all we need to do is implement `MYTYPE_IsValid`. Doing so leaves you with two options: `1` An implementation whose name [doesn't lie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4969304/1889329) but is useless in always returning `true`. `2` An implementation that does something else than its name implies, but cannot be implemented in a generic fashion. It becomes invalid with every change to the `enum` definition, that cannot be diagnosed.

Comment: @IInspectable YMMV but I think it is not that hard to define a maintainable MYTYPE_IsValid(int) function by relying on a switch case and warnings related to non-handled enumerated value in switch case. This type of function is also useful to perform checks before casting the value when you get your value as a raw integer. (For what it's worth, my snippet was initially written for protobuf enums which do define an IsValid function).

Answer (score -2):

C++ doesn't have introspection, so you can't determine this kind of thing at run-time.

Comment: Could you explain to me why "introspection" would be needed to iterate over an enum?

Comment: Maybe the term is *Reflection*?

Comment: I'm trying to say 2 things: 1) Per many other answers C++ can accomplish this so if you're going to say it cannot, a link or further clarification is required. 2) In it's current form this is at best a comment, certainly not an answer.

Comment: Downvote my answer then - I think you've more than justified it

Comment: I'll again cram in 2 comments: 1) I don't downvote because I find that receiving a downvote demotivates site participation, I find that counterproductive 2) I still don't understand what you're trying to say but it sounds like you understand something I don't in which case I'd prefer you elaborate rather than delete a downvoted answer.

Comment: C++ indeed supports type introspection.
See typeid and dynamic_cast

Comment: Introspection is the correct term (no manipulation, only examination). While the answers statement is wrong due to RTTI methods via `typeid` and `dynamic_cast`, both are not a solution for the problem. So technically, "the introspection of C++ does not cover looking up enum values" or something would be a better answer.

Answer (score -2):

Just make an array of ints and loop over the array, but make the last element say -1 and use it for exit condition.

If enum is:

```
enum MyEnumType{Hay=12,Grass=42,Beer=39};
```

then create array:

```
int Array[] = {Hay,Grass,Beer,-1};

for (int h = 0; Array[h] != -1; h++){
  doStuff( (MyEnumType) Array[h] );
}
```

This does not break down no matter the ints in the representation as long as -1 check does not collide with one of the elements of course.