# Iteration over enum in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I have

```
enum Colour {
    white,
    pink,
    yellow,
    blue
} Colour;
```

And I would like to do something like this:

```
for (int colour in Colour) {
    // Do something here.
}
```

Can I do this and if yes, how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [looping through enum values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662719/looping-through-enum-values)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

An enum comes from, C while fast enumeration was an addition of Objective-C 2.0... They don't work together.

```
Type existingItem;
for ( existingItem in expression ) { statements }
```

An expression must conform to the NSFastEnumeration Protocol and be an Object! "elements" of an enum are not objects.

See [Apple's Fast Enumeration Documents](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH18-SW1) for more information.

Check this example to see how fast enumeration works:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
        @"One", @"Two", @"Three", @"Four", nil];

for (NSString *element in array) {
    NSLog(@"element: %@", element);
}

NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    @"quattuor", @"four", @"quinque", @"five", @"sex", @"six", nil];

NSString *key;
for (key in dictionary) {
    NSLog(@"English: %@, Latin: %@", key, [dictionary objectForKey:key]);
}
```

Comment: I don't but it will only let me do so after 5 min apparently ; )

Comment: in this answer I have a know the which value is I want index value too how can I find please help Thank You

Answer (score 155):

Although the question is already answered, here are my two cents:

```
enum Colour {
    white = 0,
    pink,
    yellow,
    blue,

    colorsCount // since we count from 0, this number will be blue+1 and will be actual 'colors count'
} Colour;

for (int i = 0; i < colorsCount; ++i)
  someFunc((Colour)i);
```

I guess it's not that bad and is pretty close to the fast enumeration you want.

Comment: That's in fact what I ended up implementing, thanks for posting it!

Comment: I'm getting errors because I `typedef`ed my enum. Is there a work around for this situation?

Comment: Clever idea, but bad smell. Sneaking functionality into an identification mechanism like an enum breaks its intent and its cohesion.

Comment: dooleyo, this kind of 'enumeration' is pretty typical for C/C++ coders. Of course, it works only for particular numeric enums.

Comment: The only problem with this idea is that when you do a switch statement on it you'd have to start always catering for this extra enum

Comment: What if I want pink to be 5, then automatically yellow would be 6, right? Then how should the 4 missed cases(1,2,3,4) would be handled ? also I can change pink case value to 60, 600 and so on.

Answer (score 13):

The "Count" element in enum is nice, but it will get you a "Not all switch cases were handled" in the `switch` statement, unless you handle this "count" element in it. A maybe little better way is to use aliases for the first and for the last elements:

```
enum Colour {
    firstColour = 0,

    white = firstColour,
    pink,
    yellow,
    blue,

    lastColour = blue
} Colour;

for (int i = firstColour; i <= lastColour; ++i) {

}
```

Comment: blue will be fired twice

Comment: @OlSen nope, as `blue` == `lastColour`

Answer (score 6):

I came to this post to answer this question as well. Gobra's answer is great. But my number of items may fluctuate, and correlate to a stored value, so to be extra safe that the "colorsCount" count is or was never a valid value, I ended up implementing the following and wanted to add to the discussion:

MYColor.h

```
typedef NS_ENUM( NSInteger, MYColorType )
{
    MYColorType0 = 0,
    MYColorType1,
    MYColorType2,
    MYColorType3
};

static inline MYColorType MYColorTypeFirst() { return MYColorType0; }
static inline MYColorType MYColorTypeLast() { return MYColorType3; }
```

ViewController.m

```
for ( int i = MYColorTypeFirst(); i <= MYColorTypeLast(); i++ )
{
    MYColor * color = [[MYColor alloc] initWithType:i];
    ...
}
```

The notable addition being the definition of MYColorTypeFirst() and MYColorTypeLast(), which is used in the for() iteration, placed near the enum definition for maintainability.

Answer (score 5):

For cases where I'm not the author of the enum, I do it like this. I think this is pretty future safe, as it doesn't cares about how the enum types are actually implemented.

```
    UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection allDirections[] = {
        UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown,
        UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft,
        UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight,
        UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(allDirections)/sizeof(allDirections[0]); ++i) {
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onSwipe:)];
        swipeGesture.direction = allDirections[i];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture];
    }
```

Comment: Don't you need to free that array when you're done..?

Comment: That array is in the stack memory, it should get automatically purged when you leave the scope.

Comment: What if I create it static and return it from a function?

Comment: If it is static, it would live forever. Can you post some code, what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

#### This is a perfect use case for using a preprocessor to avoid dirtying up your compiled code

---

In your *.h* file:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, EnumValue)
{
    EnumValueOne,
    EnumValueTwo,
    EnumValueThree,
    EnumValueFour
#define EnumValueLast EnumValueFour
};
```

Elsewhere in the application:

```
for (EnumValue value = 0; value <= EnumValueLast; value++) {
    // Do stuff
}
```