# How to enumerate over enum in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [looping through enum values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662719/looping-through-enum-values)

Suppose we're dealing with a deck of cards

```
typedef enum {
    HEARTS, CLUBS, DIAMONDS, SPADES, SUIT_NOT_DEFINED
} Suit;
```

How can i enumerate over an enum?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the lower bound of the `enum` as the starting point and test that against the upper bound in the loop condition:

```
for(int i = HEARTS; i < SUIT_NOT_DEFINED; ++i) {
   //do something with i...
}
```

Comment: Well, if SUIT_NOT_DEFINED wasn't defined, then he could still iterate as such: `for (int i=HEARTS;i<=SPADES;++i) {...}` since he isn't using a enumeration type for the loop invariant variable.