# looping through NSStringEncoding(enum) value

Tags: objective-c, c

I currently write some code to decode string using NSStringEncoding.
And I'd like to decode that string using all value of NSStringEncoding.
But I don't know how to get all value of NSStringEncoding.
I checked this article, but values of NSStringEncoding it not continuous, 
so I'm looking for better solution.
[looping through enum values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662719/looping-through-enum-values)
Anyone have good idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NSString`'s class method `availableStringEncodings` which:

> Returns a zero-terminated list of the encodings string objects support in the application’s environment.

Described another way a "zero-terminated list" is a pointer to a C-array. You can iterate over this array.

HTH