# C++: Is it possible to overload the | operator on two different enums residing inside the same class?

Tags: c++, enums, operator-overloading, operators, overloading

```
class myClass
{
    enum firstEnum { Value1, Value2, Value3};
    enum secondEnum { ValueA, ValueB, ValueC};
};
```

I want to overload the | operator on the two enums above. Is it possible?

Notice that there are two enums here, not just one and i want to overload the | for both.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operators overloading for enums](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571456/operators-overloading-for-enums)

Comment: What are you trying to do? Overloading the `|` can lead to massive confusion, especially for enums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just like you can for regular functions, you can **overload** operators for different types of arguments

```
#include <iostream>

struct myClass
{
    enum firstEnum { Value1, Value2, Value3};
    enum secondEnum { ValueA, ValueB, ValueC};

    friend void operator|(firstEnum L, firstEnum R) { std::cout << "first\n"; }
    friend void operator|(secondEnum L, secondEnum R) { std::cout << "second\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    myClass::Value1 | myClass::Value2; // first
    myClass::ValueA | myClass::ValueB; // second
    myClass::Value1 | myClass::ValueA; // prints nothing, converts enums to builtin operator|(int, int)
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/887153797ed31536).

But be careful with old-fashioned `enum`, they implicitly convert to integral types so that mixed calls to `operator|` will be calling the builtin `operator|` on `int`. Use C++11 `enum class` to get more type-safe behavior.

**Update**: the above code compiles for C++98 as well, it's just that C++11 offers more type-safe enums.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using C++98, so I cannot use enum class. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Yanniel He is not using `enum class`.  he is using a `class` that has an `enum` which is C++98 compliant.  [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1e60514b4e62e9c) is the live example in C++98 compilation

Comment: Yes, TemplateRex's solution works in C++98; but he also said "Use enum class to get more type-safe behavior", hence my previous comment.

Comment: @NathanOliver updated to avoid confusion about c++98.