# Iterate through Enums in C++

Tags: c++, enums

C++ enum question.

So I have a list of files, and their IDs that I need to iterate over, and do stuff to. Most of the stuff is the same, but there are a few file-specific things that need to be done. I tried putting the file IDs in an enum, and iterating over that. Howver, the fileIDs are non contiguous, and jump around.

Currently, I have something akin to this

```
for(int i = 0; i < FILE_ENUM_MAX; i++)
{
    currentFile = myEnum(i);
    // do stuff
}

enum myEnum {
    file1 = 0x1111,
    file2 = 0x8000,
    file3 = 0x75,
    file4 = 0x120,
    FILE_ENUM_MAX = 4
}
```

This doesn't work; I just go through files 0, 1, 2, and 3. I get the idea that I can't just get the Nth item in an enumeration by asking for item N. So what would be the best way to iterate over this enum? Or should I just get rid of it? I probably could put the items in numerical order, but I'd prefer a solution to where order didn't matter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++: Iterate through an enum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261963/c-iterate-through-an-enum)

Comment: Some good stuff in the duplicate post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the low-tech answer might be to skip the enum, and just create a static array:

```
#define ARRAYSIZE(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]))

int FILE_ENUM[] = { 0x1111, 0x8000, 0x75, 0x120 };

for(int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE(FILE_ENUM); i++) {
    currentFile = myEnum[i];
    // do stuff
}
```

TJ

Comment: Yes, until you need to change file number 54 permanently. Now, how easy is it to count 54 elements over in a list of 324? I prefer the higher-level constructs for readability and such. To each his own :)

Comment: May I suppose that you use a macro for the size because you want C-compatible code ? In C++ it's certainly unnecessary.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, C++ does not provide a way to iterate through enums like you want.

Comment: One can be written, see my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I have two suggestions:

1. Use a `std::vector` to contain the enums.
2. Use a `std::map` to contain the
   enums.

Solution 2 offers a benefit where the *key* is the file ID and the *value* can be the name of the file (or an object containing attributes of the file, such as a file handle or pointer).

Answer (score 0):

i <= FILE_ENUM_MAX and it will iterate with 4th file. Sorry if this is an old thread but maybe someone will still need an answer trying to find it here.