# How to automatically convert strongly typed enum into int?

Tags: c++, c++11, strongly-typed-enum

```
#include <iostream>

struct a {
  enum LOCAL_A { A1, A2 };
};
enum class b { B1, B2 };

int foo(int input) { return input; }

int main(void) {
  std::cout << foo(a::A1) << std::endl;
  std::cout << foo(static_cast<int>(b::B2)) << std::endl;
}
```

The `a::LOCAL_A` is what the strongly typed enum is trying to achieve, but there is a small difference : normal enums can be converted into integer type, while strongly typed enums can not do it without a cast.

So, is there a way to convert a strongly typed enum value into an integer type without a cast? If yes, how?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Strongly typed enums aiming to solve multiple problems and not only scoping problem as you mentioned in your question:

1. Provide type safety, thus eliminating implicit conversion to integer by integral promotion.
2. Specify underlying types.
3. Provide strong scoping.

Thus, it is impossible to implicitly convert a strongly typed enum to integers, or even its underlying type - that's the idea. So you have to use `static_cast` to make conversion explicit.

If your only problem is scoping and you really want to have implicit promotion to integers, then you better off using not strongly typed enum with the scope of the structure it is declared in.

Comment: That's another weird example of 'we know better what you want to do' from  C++ creators. Conventional (old-style) enums had tons of benefits like implicit conversion to indexes, seamless using of bitwise operations etc.. The new style enums added a really great scoping thing, but... You cannot use just that thing (even with explicit underlying type specification!). So now you're either forced to use old style enums with tricks like putting them into struct or create ugliest workarounds for new enums like creating your own wrapper around std::vector just to overcome that CAST thing. no comments

Comment: @avtomaton: You should be aware that regular enums *also* have scoping in C++11. Yes, they dump their enumerators out into the global scope (for backwards compatibility reasons), but you are permitted to access them through the scope of their enumeration name. "*create ugliest workarounds for new enums like creating your own wrapper around std::vector just to overcome that CAST thing*" Or... just type `static_cast`. You'll make your code make a lot more sense.

Comment: @NicolBolas You are permitted to access the regular enums through the scope even before c++11, but you are also permitted to access them without it as well even in c++11. Using `static_cast` just makes the code to look ugly and less readable. Why should I do that if I explicitly specify the underlying type? That was so elegant and  beautiful solutions with old-style enums, and the problem was their scope. The new one added scope, but removed the power of binary masks and direct value comparison. For me that's weird. And the amount of that kind of questions clearly shows that not only for me

Comment: @avtomaton: "*You are permitted to access the regular enums through the scope even before c++11*" [No, you can't.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/47bP4K)

Comment: @NicolBolas my bad, you're right, thank you for pointing on that. But that backward compatibility in c++11 encourages to use it without the scope (I've seen tons of that code with and without the scope across the sources). I'm trying to say that there is no human way to use integer-based enums supporting integer operations without any hack (like explicit casts, or wrapping in a struct, or whatever). And I still have to use old enums (and I'm wrapping them in a struct to FORCE using that artificial scope name)

Comment: What is the point of being able to say enum class MyEnum : int if you then still have to cast MyEnum::Value1 as an int when using it as an int? Why even have the ability to specify the type of the values if still you have to afterwards explicitly cast it to that type anyway? I don't get it.

Comment: @Shavais, the point is to specify the memory size needed to store the enum.

Comment: @AlexO Alright, fair enough, but shouldn't a :int be implicitly convertible to an int?

Comment: @Shavais, that would defeat the purpose (will allow comparing values from unrelated enums, etc.).  If you only want the scope, you can surround a regular `enum` by a `struct`.

Comment: @Alex Defeat the purpose? Interesting, so with struct Flowers { enum Lilly = 0, Poppy = 1; } ;  .. does it deduce the size? The values (in this case) seem to be usable as ints. 

So with enum class, even if you specify the value type, still the type of an enum class value is considered unique..

Comment: @Shavais, the main purpose of the scoped enum is to prohibit the implicit conversion.  C++03 enums can be made "scoped" by wrapping them in a struct, and scoped enums can be accessed "unscoped" in C++20 with `using enum`.  The underlying type can be specified for unscoped enums since C++11.  So the lack of implicit conversion is the only distinguishing feature left, thus "defeats the purpose".

Comment: They could have at least make `enum class`es able to get own methods. That way we could compensate for the missing implicit conversion by writing neat methods. Or just add our own `operator int()`, if we want it.

Comment: This is an obsolete answer. And somehow even inaccurate since C++23. Accepted answers should decay somehow, I think stackoverflow should implement some kind of aging to answers (and also to questions actually).

Answer (score 212):

As others have said, you can't have an implicit conversion, and that's by-design.

If you want you can avoid the need to specify the underlying type in the cast.

```
template <typename E>
constexpr typename std::underlying_type<E>::type to_underlying(E e) noexcept {
    return static_cast<typename std::underlying_type<E>::type>(e);
}

std::cout << foo(to_underlying(b::B2)) << std::endl;
```

Comment: According to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_underlying), C++23 will have a `std::to_underlying()` function template which does exactly the above.

Comment: Could that possibly get any uglier? The template makes my eye's cross and the static cast makes my hair start on fire. The standards committee needs to get its act together. Of course I can just remove the word class and we're back to the magic that made c/c++ so popular in the first place.

Comment: For novices like me) Why not just use `static_cast<int>(b::B2)`? See the [doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) for 'Scoped enumerations': One can _explicitly_ declare the underlying type, eg. `enum struct|class name : type ;` - or, the _default_ is `int`. So, in the OP's example, the underlying type is `int` since it is not set explicitly, thus `static_cast<int>(b::B2)` works.

Answer (score 129):

A C++14 version of the answer provided by [R. Martinho Fernandes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8357462/3387453) would be:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename E>
constexpr auto to_underlying(E e) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<E>>(e);
}
```

As with the previous answer, this will work with any kind of enum and underlying type.  I have added the `noexcept` keyword as it will never throw an exception.

---

*Update*
This also appears in ***Effective Modern C++ by Scott Meyers***.  See item 10 (it is detailed in the final pages of the item within my copy of the book).

---

A C++23 version would be to use the [std::to_underlying](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p1682r3.html) function:

```
#include <utility>

std::cout << std::to_underlying(b::B2) << std::endl;
```

...or if the underlying type could be a [1 byte type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28414758/3387453):

```
std::cout << +(std::to_underlying(b::B2)) << std::endl;
```

Comment: 8 byte -> 8 bit?

Answer (score 49):

The reason for the absence of implicit conversion (by design) was given in other answers.

I personally use unary `operator+` for the conversion from enum classes to their underlying type:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr auto operator+(T e) noexcept
    -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum<T>::value, std::underlying_type_t<T>>
{
    return static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<T>>(e);
}
```

Which gives quite little "typing overhead":

```
std::cout << foo(+b::B2) << std::endl;
```

Where I actually use a macro to create enums and the operator functions in one shot.

```
#define UNSIGNED_ENUM_CLASS(name, ...) enum class name : unsigned { __VA_ARGS__ };\
inline constexpr unsigned operator+ (name const val) { return static_cast<unsigned>(val); }
```

Comment: Hey @Stefan, maybe you are unaware that the unary + operator:  "Integral promotion is performed on integral operands" - so in fact this is an excellent solution and it very readable if you are aware of integral promotion.

Comment: @Dino Dini, yes, fair enough. Thanks for the clarification of the unary operator.

Answer (score 31):

Short answer is you can't as above posts point out. But for my case, I simply didn't want to clutter the namespace but still have implicit conversions, so I just did:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace Foo {
   enum Foo { bar, baz };
}

int main() {
   cout << Foo::bar << endl; // 0
   cout << Foo::baz << endl; // 1
   return 0;
}
```

The namespacing sort of adds a layer of type-safety while I don't have to static cast any enum values to the underlying type.

Comment: It adds no type safety whatsoever (indeed, you just removed the type safety) - it only adds name scoping.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes I agree. I lied. Technically, to be exact, the type is just underneath a name space/scope and fully qualifies to `Foo::Foo`. Members can be accessed as `Foo::bar` and `Foo::baz` and can be implicitly casted (and so not much type safety). It's probably better to almost always use enum classes especially if starting a new project.

Comment: I'm OK with this method, if the code really needs enums that you can treat as integers, `static_cast<>` actually hurts type safety, because it's powerful and might convert something it shouldn't.

Comment: Also another issue with `enum class` is that, well, you have to get values into this enum somehow. If you get it from file, user input, the internet, etc... it's likely going to be an `int`-ish value, so the only time you can really avoid `static_cast` for `enum class` is if the enum is only ever set using `something = SomeEnum::A`. I can't really think of many use cases which wouldn't at least require somebody to load/save their data to file.

Comment: Helped my case where I specifically used enum values as array indicies, where two enums have very similiar/identical names.

Comment: Interesting. This solves my problem: I only needed a name-spaced symbolic name, but otherwise it had to be compatible with an int. Now I have to figure out in what circumstances you really want to have an enum also be its own class.

Comment: I use this in the following way:
`namespace FooSth { enum Foo {...}; } using Foo = FooSth::Foo;` 
So then I can access the enum type with just its own name, without having to specify the namespace, but the enum members stay contained.

Comment: What a good idea. Its very handy when you want the convenience of assigning known integer values to an old-school  enum, and yet encapsulating the name to a clear, sectioned-off area.  Very handy for me, where I need to define states and errors for the software that runs our equipment, and, eventually, I must  save this state information as documented integer values chosen by others.  Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 26):

No. There is **no natural way**.

In fact, one of the motivations behind having strongly typed `enum class` in C++11 is to prevent their silent conversion to `int`.

Comment: Have a look at the reply from Khurshid Normuradov. It comes the 'natural way' and is much as intended in 'The C++ Programming Language (4th ed.)'. It does not come in an 'automatic way', and that is good about it.

Comment: @PapaAtHome I do not understand the benefit of that over static_cast. Not much change in the typing or code cleanness. What is natural way here? A function returning value?

Comment: @user2876962 The benefit, for me, is that it is not automatic or 'silent' as Iammilind puts it. That prevents dificult to find errors. You can still do a cast but you are forced to think about it. That way you know what you're doing. 
To me it is part of a 'safe coding' habit. I prefer that no conversions are not done automatic is there is a sliver of a chance that it might introduce an error. Quite a few changes in C++11 related to the type system fall in this category if you ask me.

Answer (score 21):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>

#include <type_traits>

namespace utils
{

namespace details
{

template< typename E >
using enable_enum_t = typename std::enable_if< std::is_enum<E>::value, 
                                               typename std::underlying_type<E>::type 
                                             >::type;

}   // namespace details


template< typename E >
constexpr inline details::enable_enum_t<E> underlying_value( E e )noexcept
{
    return static_cast< typename std::underlying_type<E>::type >( e );
}   


template< typename E , typename T>
constexpr inline typename std::enable_if< std::is_enum<E>::value &&
                                          std::is_integral<T>::value, E
                                         >::type 
 to_enum( T value ) noexcept 
 {
     return static_cast<E>( value );
 }

} // namespace utils




int main()
{
    enum class E{ a = 1, b = 3, c = 5 };

    constexpr auto a = utils::underlying_value(E::a);
    constexpr E    b = utils::to_enum<E>(5);
    constexpr auto bv = utils::underlying_value(b);

    printf("a = %d, b = %d", a,bv);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This does not reduce typing or make code cleaner and has the side effects of making it tougher to find such implicit conversions in big projects. Static_cast would be easier to search project wide than these constructs.

Comment: @AtulKumar How is searching for static_cast easier than searching for to_enum?

Comment: This answer needs some explanation and documentation.

Comment: I agree that having an enum_cast or similar keyword, is better that relying on the static_cast keyword everywhere. When reading the code back I have to look at each static_cast and decide from the context what it might be doing, whereas enum_cast/narrow_cast/up_cast/down_cast all make it clearer what the static_cast is doing, and with the SFINAE clauses, I can be sure the name is what is happening,

Answer (score 12):

Hope this helps you or someone else

```
enum class EnumClass : int //set size for enum
{
    Zero, One, Two, Three, Four
};

union Union //This will allow us to convert
{
    EnumClass ec;
    int i;
};

int main()
{
using namespace std;

//convert from strongly typed enum to int

Union un2;
un2.ec = EnumClass::Three;

cout << "un2.i = " << un2.i << endl;

//convert from int to strongly typed enum
Union un;
un.i = 0; 

if(un.ec == EnumClass::Zero) cout << "True" << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is called "type punning" and although supported by some compilers is not portable, as the C++ standard says that after you set `un.i` that is the "active member" and you can only read the active member of a union.

Comment: @JonathanWakely You are technically correct, but I have never seen a compiler where this doesn't work reliably.  Stuff like this, anonymous unions, and #pragma once are defacto standards.

Comment: Why use something that the standard explicitly forbids, when a simple cast will do? This is just wrong.

Comment: Technically correct or not, for me it's way more readable then other solutions found here. And what is more important for me, it can be used to solve not only serialization, but also deserialization of enum class with ease, and readable format.

Comment: I absolutely despair that there are people who consider this messy undefined behaviour "way more readable" than a simple `static_cast`.

Comment: Related: [Type_punning on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning); I'm not sure if even the `may_alias` attribute will protect your union method. Currently GCC uses non-strict aliasing, so it could decide to ignore sets to the inactive field in a union.

Comment: Fails on my machine, unless I don't use optimizations.  I suppose not using optimizations is a small price to pay for doing forbidden things in the language.

Comment: @MarcinWaśniowski this is not a well defined way to handle serialization either, I've been down that road, g++ can and will ruin your day (MSVC does not have this optimization so you won't get in trouble if you only use MSVC). If you must type pun `may_alias` can help, but I don't think it will help for `union`s, note that I think this behavior is well defined in C, but not C++, it's a breaking compatibility issue between C and C++.

Answer (score 8):

This seems impossible with the native `enum class`, but probably you can mock a `enum class` with a `class`:

In this case,

```
enum class b
{
    B1,
    B2
};
```

would be equivalent to:

```
class b {
 private:
  int underlying;
 public:
  static constexpr int B1 = 0;
  static constexpr int B2 = 1;
  b(int v) : underlying(v) {}
  operator int() {
      return underlying;
  }
};
```

This is mostly equivalent to the original `enum class`. You can directly return `b::B1` for in a function with return type `b`. You can do `switch case` with it, etc.

And in the spirit of this example you can use templates (possibly together with other things) to generalize and mock any possible object defined by the `enum class` syntax.

Comment: but B1 and B2 must be defined outside the class... or this is unusable for case

 - header.h <-- class b

- main.cpp <---- myvector.push_back( B1 )

Comment: Shouldn't that be "static constexpr b" instead of "static constexpr int'? Otherwise, b::B1 is just an int with no typesafety at all.

Answer (score 7):

The C++ committee took one step forward (scoping enums out of global namespace) and fifty steps back (no enum type decay to integer).  Sadly, `enum class` is simply not usable if you need the value of the enum in any non-symbolic way.

The best solution is to not use it at all, and instead scope the enum yourself using a namespace or a struct.  For this purpose, they are interchangable.  You will need to type a little extra when refering to the enum type itself, but that will likely not be often.

```
struct TextureUploadFormat {
    enum Type : uint32 {
        r,
        rg,
        rgb,
        rgba,
        __count
    };
};

// must use ::Type, which is the extra typing with this method; beats all the static_cast<>()
uint32 getFormatStride(TextureUploadFormat::Type format){
    const uint32 formatStride[TextureUploadFormat::__count] = {
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4
    };
    return formatStride[format]; // decays without complaint
}
```

Comment: Nice explanation. Is there any single advantage of enum class over enums within namespace or a struct?

Comment: Is there any reason to use a `struct` instead of a `namespace` for enclosing the enum?

Comment: Oh... I just thought of a reason to use struct instead of namespace, it will prevent you from accidentally defining the same enum "namespace" twice. E.g., if `TextureUploadFormat` was a namespace, you could use that namespace more than once and accidentally merge the namespaces of the two Enums.

Comment: @jrh, the main reason is that you can't name your enum type optimally with the wrapper namespace technique: on the one hand you want the namespace itself be the enum type name (so you can write `DescriptiveEnumTypeName::Value`), but OTOH how would you name the _actual_ `enum` type then? Whatever you call that, the actual type name will show up in declarations like `DescriptiveEnumTypeName::RealEnumTypeName`, which is... depressing.

Comment: Then, if you finally give up hope and surrender to a `struct`, a little bit of reward is that you can now naturally & gradually extend/harden it (with some tedium, which is also depressing, but at least doable) to achieve some of the good stuff of an enum class, if you later wish to.

Answer (score 5):

As many said, there is no way to automatically convert without adding overheads and too much complexity, but you can reduce your typing a bit and make it look better by using lambdas if some cast will be used a bit much in a scenario. That would add a bit of function overhead call, but will make code more readable compared to long static_cast strings as can be seen below. This may not be useful project wide, but only class wide.

```
#include <bitset>
#include <vector>

enum class Flags { ......, Total };
std::bitset<static_cast<unsigned int>(Total)> MaskVar;
std::vector<Flags> NewFlags;

-----------
auto scui = [](Flags a){return static_cast<unsigned int>(a); };

for (auto const& it : NewFlags)
{
    switch (it)
    {
    case Flags::Horizontal:
        MaskVar.set(scui(Flags::Horizontal));
        MaskVar.reset(scui(Flags::Vertical)); break;
    case Flags::Vertical:
        MaskVar.set(scui(Flags::Vertical));
        MaskVar.reset(scui(Flags::Horizontal)); break;

   case Flags::LongText:
        MaskVar.set(scui(Flags::LongText));
        MaskVar.reset(scui(Flags::ShorTText)); break;
    case Flags::ShorTText:
        MaskVar.set(scui(Flags::ShorTText));
        MaskVar.reset(scui(Flags::LongText)); break;

    case Flags::ShowHeading:
        MaskVar.set(scui(Flags::ShowHeading));
        MaskVar.reset(scui(Flags::NoShowHeading)); break;
    case Flags::NoShowHeading:
        MaskVar.set(scui(Flags::NoShowHeading));
        MaskVar.reset(scui(Flags::ShowHeading)); break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

### Summary

**Question:**

> is there a way to convert a strongly typed enum value into an integer type without a cast? If yes, how?

**Answer:**

No, there is not. Strongly typed enums can NOT be converted to integers without an explicit cast. Weak enums can, however, as they will be automatically implicitly cast. So, if you'd like automatic implicit conversion to an int, consider using a C-style weak enum instead (see more on this in the "Going further" section below).

From here (emphasis added): https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum --> under the section "Scoped enumerations":

> There are **no implicit conversions from the values of a *scoped enumerator*** [AKA: "strong enum"] to integral types, although `static_cast` may be used to obtain the numeric value of the enumerator.

### Going further: discussion of *weak* (C-style) vs *strong* (C++ `enum class`) enum types in C++

In C++ there are **two types of enums:**

1. "unscoped", "regular", "weak", "weakly typed", or "C-style" enums, and
2. "scoped", "strong", "strongly typed", "enum class", or "C++-style" enums.

"Scoped" enums, or "strong" enums, give two additional "features" beyond what "regular" enums give you.

Scoped enums:

1. don't allow implicit casting from the enum type to an integer type (so you **can't** do what you want to do *implicitly*!), and
2. they "scope" the enum so that you have to access the enum through its enum type name.

#### 1. Example of an enum class (available only in C++):

```
// enum class (AKA: "strong" or "scoped" enum)
enum class my_enum
{
    A = 0,
    B,
    C,
};

my_enum e = my_enum::A; // scoped through `my_enum::`
e = my_enum::B;

// NOT ALLOWED!:
//   error: cannot convert ‘my_enum’ to ‘int’ in initialization
// int i = e; 

// But explicit casting works just fine!:
int i1 = static_cast<int>(e); // explicit C++-style cast 
int i2 = (int)e;              // explicit C-style cast
```

The first "feature" may actually be something you *don't* want, in which case you just need to use a regular C-style enum instead! And the nice thing is: you can still "scope" or "namespace" the enum, as has been done in C for decades, by simply prepending its name with the enum type name, like this:

#### 2. Example of a regular enum (available in both C and C++):

```
// regular enum (AKA: "weak" or "C-style" enum)
enum my_enum
{
    // C-style-scoped through the `MY_ENUM_` prefix
    MY_ENUM_A = 0,
    MY_ENUM_B,
    MY_ENUM_C,
};

my_enum e = MY_ENUM_A; // scoped through `MY_ENUM_`
e = MY_ENUM_B;

// This works fine!
int i = e;
```

Notice you still get the benefit of "scoping" simply by adding the `MY_ENUM_` "scope" to the front of each enum!

#### 3. Both regular enums and enum classes together:

Test the code here: https://onlinegdb.com/BkWGqlqz_.

**main.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

// enum class (AKA: "strong" or "scoped" enum [available only in C++, not C])
enum class my_enum
{
    A = 0,
    B,
    C,
};

// regular enum (AKA: "weak" or "C-style" enum [available in BOTH C and C++])
enum my_enum2
{
    MY_ENUM_A = 0,
    MY_ENUM_B,
    MY_ENUM_C,
};


int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");

    // 1) scoped enum

    my_enum e = my_enum::A; // scoped through `my_enum::`
    e = my_enum::B;
    
    // IMPLICIT CASTING TO INT IS NOT ALLOWED!
    // int i = e; // "error: cannot convert ‘my_enum’ to ‘int’ in initialization"
    // But this explicit C++-style cast works fine:
    int i1 = static_cast<int>(e); 
    // This explicit C-style cast works fine too, and is easier to read
    int i2 = (int)e;
    
    
    // 2) regular enum 
    
    my_enum2 e2 = MY_ENUM_A; // scoped through `MY_ENUM_`
    e2 = MY_ENUM_B;
    
    // This implicit cast works fine / IS allowed on C-style enums!
    int i3 = e2;
    // These explicit casts are also fine, but explicit casting is NOT 
    // required for regular enums.
    int i4 = static_cast<int>(e2); // explicit C++-style cast 
    int i5 = (int)e2;              // explicit C-style cast 

    return 0;
}
```

### 4. How to iterate over enums:

1. *****[my answer] Full examples of how to iterate over both 1. *weakly-typed C-style* and 2. *scoped, strongly-typed C++ `enum class`* enums: [How can I iterate over an enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69774217/4561887)
2. [my Q&A] [What are commonly-used ways to iterate over an enum class in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69762682/4561887)

Answer (score 2):

An extension to the answers from [R. Martinho Fernandes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8357462/3387453) and [Class Skeleton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33083231/5747415): Their answers show how to use `typename std::underlying_type<EnumType>::type` or `std::underlying_type_t<EnumType>` to convert your enumeration value with a `static_cast` to a value of the underlying type.  Compared to a `static_cast` to some specific integer type, like, `static_cast<int>` this has the benefit of being maintenance friendly, because when the underlying type changes, the code using `std::underlying_type_t` will automatically use the new type.

This, however, is sometimes not what you want: Assume you wanted to print out enumeration values directly, for example to `std::cout`, like in the following example:

```
enum class EnumType : int { Green, Blue, Yellow };
std::cout << static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<EnumType>>(EnumType::Green);
```

If you later change the underlying type to a character type, like, `uint8_t`, then the value of `EnumType::Green` will not be printed as a number, but as a character, which is most probably not what you want.  Thus, you sometimes would rather convert the enumeration value into something like "underlying type, but with integer promotion where necessary".

It would be possible to apply the unary `operator+` to the result of the cast to force integer promotion if necessary.  However, you can also use `std::common_type_t` (also from header file `<type_traits>`) to do the following:

```
enum class EnumType : int { Green, Blue, Yellow };
std::cout << static_cast<std::common_type_t<int, std::underlying_type_t<EnumType>>>(EnumType::Green);
```

Preferrably you would wrap this expression in some helper template function:

```
template <class E>
constexpr std::common_type_t<int, std::underlying_type_t<E>>
enumToInteger(E e) {
    return static_cast<std::common_type_t<int, std::underlying_type_t<E>>>(e);
}
```

Which would then be more friendly to the eyes, be maintenance friendly with respect to changes to the underlying type, and without need for tricks with `operator+`:

```
std::cout << enumToInteger(EnumType::Green);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to make a similar (but maybe a bit faked) behaviour using an object, a constructor taking the enum in, and a conversion operator to convert to the enum like so:

```cpp
// Defines the keys that may be used to recieve input
struct Key
{
    enum KeyEnum : unsigned int {
        A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z, Numeric0, Numeric1, Numeric2, Numeric3, Numeric4, Numeric5, Numeric6, Numeric7, Numeric8, Numeric9,
        Space, LeftBracket, RightBracket, Semicolon, Apostrophe, Backslash, Slash, Comma, Dot, Backspace, LeftShift, RightShift, LeftCtrl, RightCtrl, LeftAlt, RightAlt, COUNT, UNKNOWN
    };

    Key(const KeyEnum key);

    operator KeyEnum() const;

private:
    KeyEnum key;
};
```

Where the constructor simply sets `key` and the conversion operator returns it. Which then allows me to make a Key (unsigned integer representing a keyboard key in this scenario) via 'Key::A' for example.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible bro

```
namespace MyEnumClass
{
    enum
    {
        A = 0, B,
    };
};
```

enum-class like syntax

```
typedef enum
{
    A = 0, B
} MyEnum;
```

enum-like syntax

cheers!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).