# scoped but "semi-weakly" typed enumerations

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

I want to use enumerations in a scoped format but be able to do comparison and assignment between the enumeration and unsigned integers.

This is what I have tried the code below, which works as expected:

```
class SystemEvents {
public:
    enum {
        Opened, Closed
    };
};

class OtherEvents {
public:
  enum {
     Closed,Opened
  };
};

//test
uint32_t e = SystemEvents::Opened;
if(e == OtherEvents::Closed) std::cout << "enums are weakly typed and scoped";
```

But I want to know if there is a way of doing it with the C++11 syntax?

```
enum class SystemEvents : uint32_t {
   Opened,Closed
};

enum class OtherEvents : uint32_t {
   Closed,Opened
};

//test
uint32_t e = SystemEvents::Opened;
if(e == OtherEvents::Closed) std::cout << "enums are weakly typed and scoped";
```

The code above gives me error as expected `Cannot initialize a variable of type int with an rvalue of type SystemEvents`. So, Should I stick with the C style scoped enumerations or is there a way of doing it in C++11? Or is there some other way of doing this?

Comment: Why are you using two different enums to indicate the same thing?

Comment: I started to think about what I am trying to do, and maybe it would be enough for me to use weakly typed enumerations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the initialization there is not much you can do other than cast the value. Note that C++11's strongly typed enums are not meant to replace but rather complement the existing enums. If you *want* a weakly-typed enum, just don't use `enum class`.

For the comparison of a strongly-typed enum, you can declare the necessary operators and cast inside the implementation:

```
bool operator==( uint32_t lhs, SystemEvents rhs )
{
    return static_cast< SystemEvent >( lhs ) == rhs;
}
```

Of course you need both directions:

```
bool operator==( SystemEvents lhs, uint32_t rhs );
```

And other operators like `!=`.

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly cast an enum class to an integral type, for example:

```
static_cast<uint32_t>(SystemEvents::Opened)
```

You could also write [a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8357462/150634) that will cast to the underlying type of any enum class.

However, needing to do this suggests that you're doing something wrong. Why are you trying to compare `SystemEvents` with `OtherEvents`?

Comment: I am mostly trying to compare uint32_t to SystemEvents. I put the other one as just to test the scopedness.