# c++ how to have same enum members name in different enum names without getting err:redefinition; previous definition was 'enumerator'

Tags: c++, enums

I have config file that I include in all my files 
there I have different enums but inside each enum there are same element names 
for example: config.h

```
enum GameObjectType
{
     NINJA_PLAYER

};
enum GameObjectTypeLocation
{
    NONE,
    MASSAGE_ALL,  //this is for ComponentMadiator
    NINJA_PLAYER


};
```

But when I try to compile the project with calling the enums with the proper enum name

```
m_pNinjaPlayer = (NinjaPlayer*)GameFactory::Instance().getGameObj(GameObjectType::NINJA_PLAYER);
    ComponentMadiator::Instance().Register(GameObjectTypeLocation::NINJA_PLAYER,m_pNinjaPlayer);
```

I am getting compilation error:

```
error C2365: 'NINJA_PLAYER' : redefinition; previous definition was 'enumerator' (..\Classes\GameFactory.cpp)
2>          d:\dev\cpp\2d\cocos2d-x-3.0\cocos2d-x-3.0\projects\lettersfun\classes\config.h(22) : see declaration of 'NINJA_PLAYER'
```

How can I keep in the config.h several enums with different names BUT with same elements names ?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The problem is that old-style enumerations are unscoped. You can avoid this problem (provided your compiler has the relevant C++11 support) by using scoped enumerations:

```
enum class GameObjectType { NINJA_PLAYER };

enum class GameObjectTypeLocation { NONE, MASSAGE_ALL, NINJA_PLAYER };
```

Alternatively, you can put your old-school enumerations in namespaces:

```
namespace foo
{
  enum GameObjectType { NINJA_PLAYER };
} // namespace foo

namespace bar
{
  enum GameObjectTypeLocation { NONE, MASSAGE_ALL, NINJA_PLAYER };
} // namespace bar
```

Then your enum values will be `foo::NINJA_PLAYER`, `bar::NINJA_PLAYER` etc.

Comment: Thanks didn't know c++ 11 can use class in enums

Comment: @diego.martinez It is not OS dependent. It is a C++ thing.

Comment: @juanchopanza sorry, I meant that while my visual studio 2012 compiles just fine, gcc throws errors.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8357366/4669135) the `namespace` hack to scope standard enums seems to be the only solution **if you do not want to use enum class** because of their need of `static_cast` to get an integer value.

Answer (score 13):

If you have the possibility to use C++11 I would recommend  to use enum class feature to avoid collisions:

```
enum class GameObjectType
{
     NINJA_PLAYER

};
enum class GameObjectTypeLocation
{
    NONE,
    MASSAGE_ALL,  //this is for ComponentMadiator
    NINJA_PLAYER


};
```

Edit: If you do not have this ability, then you will need to use two different namespaces for each enum.

Comment: Two different namespaces, or wrap each enum with a class.