# Comparing enums to integers

Tags: c++, enums

I've read that you shouldn't trust on the underlying implementation of an enum on being either signed or unsigned. From this I have concluded that you should always cast the enum value to the type that it's being compared against. Like this:

```
enum MyEnum { MY_ENUM_VALUE = 0 };

int i = 1;
if (i > static_cast<int>(MY_ENUM_VALUE))
{
    // do stuff
}

unsigned int u = 2;
if (u > static_cast<unsigned int>(MY_ENUM_VALUE))
{
    // do more stuff
}
```

Is this the best practice?

Edit: Does the situation change if the enum is anonymous?

Answer (score 7):

An `enum` is an integer so you can compare it against any other integer, and even floats. The compiler will automatically convert both integers to the largest, or the enum to a double before the compare.

Now, if your enumeration is not supposed to represent a number per se, you may want to consider creating a class instead:

```
enum class some_name { MY_ENUM_VALUE, ... };

int i;
if(i == static_cast<int>(some_name::MY_ENUM_VALUE))
{
    ...
}
```

In that case you need a cast because an enum class is not viewed as an integer by default. This helps quite a bit to avoid bugs in case you were to misuse an enum value...

---

**Update:** also, you can now specify the type of integer of an `enum`. This was available in older compilers too, but it was often not working quite right (in my own experience).

```
enum class some_name : uint8_t { ... };
```

That means the enumeration uses `uint8_t` to store those values. Practical if you are using enumeration values in a structure used to send data over a network or save in a binary file where you need to know the exact size of the data.

When not specified, the type defaults to `int`.

---

As brought up by others, if the point of using `enum` is *just* to declare numbers, then using `constexpr` is probably better.

```
constexpr int MY_CONSTANT_VALUE = 0;
```

This has the same effect, only the type of `MY_CONSTANT_VALUE` is now an `int`. You could go a little further and use `typedef` as in:

```
typedef int my_type_t;
constexpr my_type_t MY_CONSTANT_VALUE = 0;
```

I often use `enum` even if I'm to use a single value when the value is not generally considered an integer. There is no set in stone rule in this case.

Comment: ***if your enumeration is not supposed to represent a number per se**, you may want to consider creating a class instead* How to understand the text in bold in the right way? Is not the `MY_ENUM_VALUE` in your example equivalent to `0`, even though you didn't explicitly define that.

Comment: ***An enum is an integer so you can compare it against any other integer, and even floats.*** Is it still right with the strongly typed `enum`?

Comment: @John Internally, `enum class ...` are still just integers. However, trying to do `i == some_name::MY_ENUM_VALUE` fails with a warning (or an error if you use `-Werror`). You can use the `static_cast` to convert between those types. However, by default (without a cast) it allows you to be more sure you are using the correct type at the correct location (i.e. calling a function which expects a `some_name` won't compile when you try to pass `0` instead of `some_name::MY_ENUM_VALUE`—you could cast the `0`, however.) I think it makes your code more secure/less likely to have a bug.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: **Yes**

`enum` is `signed int` type, but they get implicitly cast into `unsigned int`. Your compiler might give a warning without explicit casting, but its still very commonly used. however you should explicitly cast to make it clear to maintainers.

And of course, [explicit cast will be must when its a *strongly typed enum*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357240/how-to-automatically-convert-strongly-typed-enum-into-int).

Comment: "enum is signed int type, but they get implicitly cast into unsigned int" This is wrong. The underlying type of an unscoped `enum` is an integer type that can fit the largest enumerator. This means that if it is bigger than `INT_MAX` it can be `unsigned int`, `long`, `unsigned long`, etc. And it is implicitly cast to the smallest integer type that can fit the largest enumerator (which isn't always `unsigned int`).

Answer (score -1):

Best practice is not to write

```
int i = 1;
if (i > static_cast<int>(MY_ENUM_VALUE))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

instead write

```
MyEnumValue i = MY_ENUM_VALUE ;
...
if ( i > MY_ENUM_VALUE ) {..}
```

But if - as in your example - you only have one value in your enum it is better to declare it as a constant instead of an enum.

Comment: I agree that this situation mostly arises when a value that should have been defined as a constant is defined in an enum.