# How to access an C++11 enum class from another file?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, enums

I have a header file that will eventually include more than one enum class. However, when I include the header file in another file and try to use the enum class, my program will not compile. For example:

enums.h:

```
#ifndef ENUMS_H
#define ENUMS_H

enum class TokenType : char
{
     IDEN,
     STRING,
     SEMICO
};

#endif
```

and main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "enums.h"

int main()
{
     char token = TokenType::STRING; //Does not compile!
}
```

**However, when I use a regular enum, it compiles correctly:**

enums.h:

```
#ifndef ENUMS_H
#define ENUMS_H

enum TokenType : char
{
     IDEN,
     STRING,
     SEMICO
}

#endif
```

and main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "enums.h"

int main()
{
     char token = STRING; //This does compile!
}
```

Does anyone know how to do this correctly? I've searched a lot and came up with nothing.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31bbc9e67f0ebd36

Comment: `TokenType` is *not* a `char` even if its underlying type is. It is its own type and does not implicitly convert. You need to use a variable of the correct (`TokenType`) type or use an explicit cast. This, by the way, is a *good* thing compared to old `enum`s.

Answer (score 3):

`enum class` do not participate in implicit conversion whereas unscoped enums do. Thus,

```
int main()
{
     TokenType token = TokenType::STRING;
}
```

will compile.

You can see [How to automatically convert strongly typed enum into int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357240/how-to-automatically-convert-strongly-typed-enum-into-int) how to otherwise convert an `enum class` to some other value.

Answer (score 0):

Enum is strongly type and you cannot assign enum to an int or char without casting it.
You can try:

```
int main() 
{
  char token = (char)TokenType::STRING; 
}
```

Comment: Prefer C++style casts over C-style casts if you *must* use a cast (always prefer *not* to). In this case `static_cast<char>`.