# How to iterator the enum in c++ like java?

Tags: c++, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++: Iterate through an enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261963/c-iterate-through-an-enum)

I have following enum in c++;

```
typedef enum
{
    APP_NONE = 0,
    APP_SESSION = 0x80000001,
    APP_TITLE = 2,
} APP_TYPE;
```

I am writing a test function, which accept a string, get related integer, such as: getEnumByString("APP_NONE") = 0; 
or vice verse getEnumString(0)="APP_NONE".

Is it possible and how to finish it?

Comment: It is impossible after more investigation, since enum is just integer in runtime, no related string name information.

Answer (score 1):

You can push the `enum` values into a container, like a vector or a set, and iterate through that.

```
std::vector<APP_TYPE> types;
types.push_back(APP_NONE);
types.push_back(APP_SESSION);
types.push_back(APP_TITLE);
```

You can use a map to associate the `enum` values with a string and vice versa.

```
std::map<APP_TYPE, std::string> type2string;
type2string[APP_NONE] = "APP_NONE";
type2string[APP_SESSION] = "APP_SESSION";
type2string[APP_TITLE] = "APP_TITLE";
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42035/Enum-to-String-and-Vice-Versa-in-C