# Is there an alternative to this long list of "if argA == argB do ..."?

Tags: c++, oop, enums

**Edit: since attack.condition will occasionally have multiple values, a switch statement won't work!**

So I have this enum **which is going to grow**:

```
enum Condition {    Null            =   0x0001,
            SelfIsUnderground   =   0x0002,
            SelfIsGround        =   0x0004,
            SelfIsAir       =   0x0008,
            SelfIsWater     =   0x0010,
            OtherIsUnderground  =   0x0020,
            OtherIsGround       =   0x0040,
            OtherIsAir      =   0x0080,
            OtherIsWater        =   0x0100,
            Tile            =   0x0200,
            CONDITION_COUNTX    =   0x03FF};
```

and this function which is also going to grow:

```
bool Attack::CanBeDone(Spirit* pSelf, Spirit* pTarget,Map* pMap)
{
    if(this->condition!=Null)
    {
        if(this->condition & SelfIsUnderground)
            if(pSelf->GetcurrentLayer()!=Underground)
                return false;

        if(this->condition & SelfIsGround)
            if(pSelf->GetcurrentLayer()!=Ground)
                return false;

        if(this->condition & SelfIsAir)
            if(pSelf->GetcurrentLayer()!=Air)
                return false;

        if(this->condition & SelfIsWater)
            if(pSelf->GetcurrentLayer()!=Water)
                return false;

        if(this->condition & OtherIsUnderground)
            if(pTarget->GetcurrentLayer()!=Underground)
                return false;

        if(this->condition & OtherIsGround)
            if(pTarget->GetcurrentLayer()!=Ground)
                return false;

        ...
```

Is there an alternative to writing over and over again:

```
    if(this->condition & arg)
        if(pSelf->GetcurrentLayer()!=value)
            return false;
```

?

Bonus: Will it work if I give Condition::Null the value 0x0000, SelfIsUnderground 0x0001, SelfIsGround 0x0002 and go with powers of 2 again? Eventually, Tile would end up with the value 0x0100.

Comment: What can I buy with my bonus points?

Comment: I didn't mention the word "points" :p

Comment: Can't you loop through the `enum` values? See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261963/c-iterate-through-an-enum

Comment: Is a `switch` statement the kind of thing you're looking for?

Comment: @l19 That only works in that case because unnumbered enum values increment, here the OP has given them explicit bitmap values.

Comment: How do I do a switch statement considering the fact that condition may and will occasionally have more than one value?

Edit: As loganfsmyth points out, I can't.

Comment: @drewmm Since attack.condition will occasionally have multiple values, a switch statement won't work.

Comment: Which problem are you actually trying to solve, though?  If you just want to reduce line count, you could do some clever hackery, but that would reduce your readability.  If you want to do a loop over binary values, then you could have a loop with a bitshift - `for (int i = 1; i < WHATEVER; i << 1) { }`.

Comment: @Infiltrator: Did you mean `i <<= 1;`?

Comment: I wanted a better way than what I did but in the end I guess what I did is alright.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes, I did.  Missed the `=`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First, I would write something like that:

```
enum Condition {    Null            =   0x0001,
            SelfBase        =   0x0002,
            SelfIsUnderground   =   SelfBase * (1 << Underground),
            SelfIsGround        =   SelfBase * (1 << Ground),
            SelfIsAir       =   SelfBase * (1 << Air),
            SelfIsWater     =   SelfBase * (1 << Water),
            SelfMask        =   SelfBase * ((1 << Max) - 1),
            OtherBase       =   0x0020,
            OtherIsUnderground  =   OtherBase * (1 << Underground),
            OtherIsGround       =   OtherBase * (1 << Ground),
            OtherIsAir      =   OtherBase * (1 << Air),
            OtherIsWater        =   OtherBase * (1 << Water),
            OtherMask       =   OtherBase * ((1 << Max) - 1),
            Tile            =   0x0200,
            CONDITION_COUNTX    =   0x03FF};
```

(assuming that `Underground == 0` and `Max == Water + 1`). Then, the long list reduces to two rather crisp expressions:

```
if ( (SelfMask & this->condition & (SelfBase * (1 << pSelf->GetcurrentLayer()))) )
    return false;

if ( (OtherMask & this->condition & (OtherBase * (1 << pTarget->GetcurrentLayer()))) )
    return false;

return true;
```

This remains correct as you expand your enums. Note however that there's still some redundancy (e.g., how `OtherBase` and `Tile` are defined), which could be reduced too. Static asserts can help to make sure that the `Condition` enum is well-defined.

Comment: `N * (1 << X)` is the same as `N << X`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I find my version easier to understand than, say, `SelfBase << Underground`. Leave some work for the optimizer :-)

Comment: I like what you did. It is late and I'll go to sleep but I'll look at that into details tomorow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you tie the `Layer` and `Condition` enums together, you can write something on the lines of:

```
enum Condition {    Null            =   0x0001,
    SelfIsUnderground   =   0x0002,
    SelfIsGround        =   0x0004,
    SelfIsAir       =   0x0008,
    SelfIsWater     =   0x0010,
    OtherIsUnderground  =   0x0020,
    OtherIsGround       =   0x0040,
    OtherIsAir      =   0x0080,
    OtherIsWater        =   0x0100,
    Tile            =   0x0200,
    CONDITION_COUNTX    =   0x03FF};

enum Layer
{
    Ground = SelfIsGround,
    Underground = SelfIsUnderground,
    Air = SelfIsAir,
    Water =  SelfIsWater
};

struct Spirit
{
    Layer GetcurrentLayer() const;

};

struct Map;

struct Attack
{
    Condition condition;
    bool CanBeDone(Spirit* pSelf, Spirit* pTarget,Map* pMap)
    {
        return (condition & pSelf->GetcurrentLayer() )&&
             ( (condition / 0x10) & pTarget->GetcurrentLayer());
    }

};
```

More likely, I'd expect you to define `Condition` in terms of `Layer`, but that's just details.

Comment: Can you express the hard-coded `0x10` in terms of the values defined in the enum? Otherwise you'll have to remember to update this code as you enhance the enum.

Comment: @krlmr. Well of course, in real code you'd encapsulate this however you'd like.

Comment: @krlmr. Just read your answer. I'm not really saying anything more.

Comment: Hint: `>> 0x10` is a bit of an overshoot. How much is `OtherIsUnderground / SelfIsUnderground`? -- Your solution is just another way to achieve the same result, with some advantages and some drawbacks.

Comment: Layers play a much larger role than what is shown in my question. For this reason, I cannot do what you say.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you get for prematurely optimizing, using bitmasks and bitwise operations; there's no simple alternative.

Why not `std::vector<Layer> selfLayers, otherLayers`? (Or can you not have multiple layers - your code implies you can.)
Or maybe use a map from layer to requiredConditionBits?

Also, I don't understand why the `Attack` class is storing conditions for two `Spirit`s. Who sets `Attack::condition` in the first place?

I would start by not using bit maps for things that are not bits or enums for things that are not enumerations. I would consider spending some time creating simple classes (such as `Layer`, `Condition`) and helper functions (`Attack::getSourceLayer` maybe? I'm too confused to be sure.) I would also review my class relationships to make sure that `Attack` really needs `condition` flags et cetera.

Comment: Layers play a much larger role than what is shown in my question. For this reason, I cannot do what you say.

Answer (score 0):

I would say abandon the `Condition` enumeration entirely, and use a struct instead.  The conditions for the self and the target are seperate and should be treated as such

```
enum Layer : char //only takes 1 byte
{
    Ground      = 1<<0,
    Underground = 1<<1,
    Air         = 1<<2,
    Water       = 1<<3
};
struct Condition {
    Layer Self;
    Layer Target;
};
bool Attack::CanBeDone(Spirit* pSelf, Spirit* pTarget,Map* pMap) {
    return this->Condition.Self & pSelf->GetcurrentLayer() 
        && this->Condition.Target & pTarget->GetcurrentLayer();
}
```