# Safely convert enum class from underlying type

Tags: c++, enums, integer, c++17

Let's say I have a strongly typed enum type like this:

```
enum class message : int {
    JOIN = 0,
    LEAVE = 4,
    SPAWN = 1,
}
```

And I need to safely (safely in this case means discarding invalid variants) convert it from it's underlying type (int).

For this purpose, I have a function to convert it for me:

```
std::optional<message> get_message(int num) {
    return num == (int)message::JOIN || num == (int)message::LEAVE || num == (int)message::SPAWN ? (message)num : {};
}
```

This works, but is long to write and prone to mistakes, especially for enums with a larger number of variants.

Is there a way to automate this process in C++17?

Comment: Any `int` value is a valid value for `message`. If you want to check whether value is one of the predefined constants then yes, you will need perform manual mapping. It can be simplified with macros.

Comment: Simply a `std::set<message>` would do. A sorted `constexpr` array would also work well with binary search.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux how would `std:set` help to filter out undefined values?

Comment: A `switch` would be cleaner than `||` comparisons: `std::optional<message> get_message(int num) { switch (num) { case message::JOIN: case message::LEAVE: case message::SPAWN: return static_cast<message>(num); } return {}; }` but in general, you can't automate this unless your enum values are sequential, then you could simply use `>=` and `<=` comparisons on the lower/upper values. Otherwise, there is no reflection in C++, you will have to code the allowed values explicitly

Comment: You also could use `boost::fusion`.

Comment: If the enum is short, an "or" expression will do. If the largest value does not exceed 31 (63), test `(1 << num) & mask` where `mask` combines all allowed values. In other cases, use a map.

Comment: c++ doesn't have reflection, so you have to write the check yourself :/

Comment: @YvesDaoust except that in the example given, `JOIN` is 0, so it would not appear in a `mask` of allowed enum values, unless you shift the mask bits by 1

Comment: @RemyLebeau You put the list of allowed values in a global, static member or function local static `const` container and check if `num` is in that container. `std::set` or a sorted `std::array` are good options. The goal is to only list them once and to make it easy to understand.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux ok thanks

Comment: @RemyLebeau: for the given example, the mask is 10011.

Comment: @YvesDaoust hmm, ok. I thought you were referring to simply `mask = JOIN | LEAVE | SPAWN` instead, which wouldn't work.

Comment: This is Neargye/magic_enum's `magic_enum::enum_cast`: https://github.com/Neargye/magic_enum , although that's not exactly efficient (it's doing a string comparision: https://godbolt.org/z/sItmZb ). Perhaps this magic_enum library could be used to implement this efficiently, though

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux why not `std::unordered_set` ?

Comment: @Ayxan Sure, but unless you have a lot of enums it's probably not worth the overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Talking about underlying type, we notice that this class merely obtains a type using another type as model, but it does not transform values or objects between those types.

As an option to simplify the function you could work by **iterating** in the enum,or as others said before with some type of container, by iterating the same enum as an example here: [How can I iterate over an enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261963/how-can-i-iterate-over-an-enum) 
and more information about enum just in case: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/enumerations-cpp?view=vs-2019