# Range of enums in C++

Tags: c++, enums, range, range-based-loop

I'm confused with range of enums.
I have code like this:

```
namespace regs {
enum Control_0 {
    THING1,
    THING2,
    THING3
};
enum Control_1 {
    THING100,
    THING200,
    THING300
};
const auto regs_range = {Control_0, Control_1}; //error
} // regs namespace
```

and need to itterate over this enums like range-based for:

```
for (const auto& reg : regs::regs_range) {
    get_register_data(reg);
}
```

I also need to save feature of acces of enum values like `getThingData(Control_0::THING1)`

Is it possible to implement this somehow?

For itterating over values in enum I've always used this : `const auto regs_values_range = {Control_0::THING1, Control_0::THING2, Control_0::THING3};` but in relation to range of enums it's error.

Comment: `Control_0 ` and `Control_1` are distint and unrelated types. You can use a `std::variant<Control_0, Control_1>` to store values of either of them. And `{Control_0, Control_1}` doesn't make sense because it's an attempt to make a collection of types, not of values.

Comment: What does it mean: "I also need to save feature of acces of enum values like `getThingData(Control_0::THING1)`"?

Comment: What you want is unclear and confusing? Please elaborate.

Comment: @eklund It looks like you possibly rather want `std::tuple<Control_0, Control_1>` than `std::variant<Control_0, Control_1>`.

Comment: `const auto regs_range = ...`.  What do you expect `auto` to be here? It has to be a valid C++ type. And the same applies to `const auto& reg : regs_range`. Again, what type should `reg` be? It has to be the same type for all elements of `regs_range`.

Comment: @eklund As I understand it, you want to have a single loop that iterates over THING1, THING2, THING3, THING100, THING200, THING300, in that order, right? If that's the case, I'm afraid it can't be done trivially. C++ is notoriously bad at enums. Even iterating on a single enum is hard, look at this: [How can I iterate over an enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261963/how-can-i-iterate-over-an-enum)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
const auto regs_range = {Control_0, Control_1};
```

Attempts to create a collection of **types** (`Control_0` and `Control_1`), not **values**.
This is invalid.
Also note that `Control_0` and `Control_1` are distinct and unrelated types and so you cannot put values from them *in a trivial way* in one collection.

**The proper solution depends on what you actually need to achieve:**

1. If you need to represent a value that can be **either** one of the entries from `Control_0` **or** the entries from `Control_1`, you can use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant):

   ```
   std::variant<Control_0, Control_1>
   ```
2. If on the other hand you would like to represent a value which is a pair - one entry from `Control_0` **together with** one entry from `Control_1`, you can use one of the following:
   (1) [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple):

   ```
   std::tuple<Control_0, Control_1>
   ```

   (2) [`std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair)

   ```
   std::pair<Control_0, Control_1>
   ```

   (3) Create your own type holding one of each:

   ```
   struct Control_0_1
   {
       Control_0 ctrl0;
       Control_1 ctrl1;
   };
   ```

   IMHO option (3) is the best in this case as it will make your code clearer.

Finally you can store any of the above in a container (e.g. `std::vector` or any other) and iterate over them.

Answer (score 0):

> but in relation to range of enums it's error.

The problem is that `Control_0` and `Control_1` are **types** not values so `const auto regs_range = {Control_0, Control_1}` is invalid.

[`std::tuple<Control_0, Control_1>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) might suit more for your problem.